# LDAP error code 21 - difference between " and ”

Tags: java, swing, encoding, ldap

I was updating information in LDAP and what I did was write text in word file and copy paste in swing text box(my java program to write into LDAP) and click "Write to LDAP".

But I get error as shown below :

[image]

So turns out, error is because of `”` (quotation mark copied from word doc that is different from `"` when directly written in swing text box).

From the error, I understand that `”` is not in ASCII encoding but I am not able to find which encoding is this?

What are the different encoding schemes for `”` and `"`? And does LDAP only supports ASCII characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDAP supports UTF-8. However, the syntax [IA5String is limited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA5STRING).
-jim

Answer (score 1):

Yes, LDAP supports only ASCII.

I would usually paste the text to 'notepad' and save as '.txt' with 'Encoding- ASCII' before storing anything into LDAP.

You need to refer the source document to find out the particular " encoding.